# is a "non-decreasing" sequence "increasing"?

Tags: algorithm

While studying the book "Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen", I found a strange thing. Everywhere if it refers to an increasing order, the book refers it as "non-decreasing" order.. I mean, if a series (2,5,6,3) is to be arranged in "non-decreasing" order.. is'nt it already right?? or "increasing" and "non-decreasing" words mean one and the same?

Comment: non-decreasing means every next element isn't less then previous, and increasing means every next element is greater then previous

Comment: This is a language problem and not a programming one.

Comment: Nondecreasing does not mean not increasing. Similarly (but in a different way) nonlinear does not mean not linear. And (in a yet different way) nonnegative does not mean not negative. "Non" is a treacherous suffix in English and produces quite a lot of nonsense and it is a good exercise in Euler-Venn diagrams to draw them for these 3 different situations.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Increasing - 1 2 3 4

Nondecreasing - 1 1 2 3

The difference being that in an increasing sequence, for x(n) and x(n+1), x(n+1) > x(n) whereas in a non-decreasing sequence, x(n+1) >= x(n)

Comment: This answer diverges with common mathematical terminology. See Kunal Vyas answer below.

Comment: @Yola - What do you mean by "diverges with common mathematical terminology" ? Did you mean to say that this answer is mathematically incorrect ?

Answer (score 31):

Yes,

**Monotonically Increasing** == **Increasing** == **Non-Decreasing**

`if f(a) >= f(b) for all a > b`

**Strictly Increasing Function** :

`if f(a) > f(b) for all a > b`

Comment: This answer must be the accepted one. Because it provides mathematical terminology.

Comment: This answer would be better if it had an example also.

Comment: According to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotoneIncreasing.html "Monotone Increasing: Always increasing; never remaining constant or decreasing. Also called strictly increasing." (perhaps "wrong")

Comment: @Yola But more generally, there's a reason people use "non-decreasing" instead of "increasing" -- to avoid ambiguity, in computer science _and_ in mathematics.

Answer (score 26):

1,2,3,4 is an increasing sequence or a non-decreasing sequence.

1,1,1,1 is a non-decreasing sequence but isn't an increasing sequence.

Comment: This answer diverges with common mathematical terminology. See Kunal Vyas answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Increasing means that every element is greater than the one before it. Non-decreasing means that no element is less than the element before it, or in other words: that every element is greater than *or equal to* the one before it.

Answer (score 7):

If there are duplicates in the series, then the term "non-decreasing" is more accurate that "increasing."

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the way the author defines these terms.

In your case the authors distinguish non-decreasing (1, 2, 2, 3) and increasing (1, 2, 3). This makes sense in the context of a total order, where not a > b implies a <= b.

Other people call this increasing (1, 2, 2, 3) and strictly increasing (1, 2, 3). This makes more sense in the context of a partial order, where for two distinct elements a and b it may be the case that neither a < b nor b < a holds.

Answer (score 6):

Non-decreasing means exactly that. It's not quite the same as increasing, since it does not tell you what to do with identical values.

Consider the sequence 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 . It's a non-decreasing sequence because the values are in order, yet do not strictly increase from value to value ( ie, 2 is not greater than 2).

Answer (score 1):

The series can be increasing and decreasing as others already explained but can also be non of them.

(1,3,2,4,5,9,1,0)

Is neither decreasing nor increasing. However, there are subsets like 2,4,5,9 that are increasing or 9,1,0 decreasing