# Using numpy isin element-wise between 2D and 1D arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have quite a simple scenario where I'd like to test whether both elements of a two-dimensional array are (separately) members of a larger array - for example:

```
full_array = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
sub_arrays = np.array([['A','C','F'],
                       ['B','C','E']])
np.isin(full_array, sub_arrays)
```

This gives me a single dimension output:

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

showing whether elements of full_array are present in either of the two sub-arrays. I'd like instead a two-dimensional array showing the same thing for each of the two elements in sub_arrays - so:

```
array([[ True,  False,  True, False,  False,  True],
       [ False, True,   True, False,  True,  False]])
```

Hope that makes sense and any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Broadcasting based one

A simple one would be with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) after extending one of the arrays and then any-reduction along the respective axis -

```
In [140]: (full_array==sub_arrays[...,None]).any(axis=1)
Out[140]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True, False]])
```

#### With `searchsorted`

**Specific case #1**

With `full_array` being sorted and all elements from `sub_arrays` present at least somewhere in `full_array`, we can also use `np.searchsorted` -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(full_array, sub_arrays)
out = np.zeros((sub_arrays.shape[0],len(full_array)),dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(out, idx, 1, axis=1)
```

**Specific case #2**

With `full_array` being sorted and if not all elements from `sub_arrays` are guaranteed to be present at least somewhere in `full_array`, we need one extra step -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(full_array, sub_arrays)
idx[idx==len(full_array)] = 0
out = np.zeros((sub_arrays.shape[0],len(full_array)),dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(out, idx, full_array[idx] == sub_arrays, axis=1)
```

**Generic case**

For the truly generic case of `full_array` not necessarily being sorted, we need to use `sorter` arg with `searchsorted` -

```
def isin2D(full_array, sub_arrays):
    out = np.zeros((sub_arrays.shape[0],len(full_array)),dtype=bool)
    sidx = full_array.argsort()
    idx = np.searchsorted(full_array, sub_arrays, sorter=sidx)
    idx[idx==len(full_array)] = 0
    idx0 = sidx[idx]
    np.put_along_axis(out, idx0, full_array[idx0] == sub_arrays, axis=1)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [214]: full_array
Out[214]: array(['E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C'], dtype='|S1')

In [215]: sub_arrays
Out[215]: 
array([['Z', 'C', 'F'],
       ['B', 'C', 'E']], dtype='|S1')

In [216]: isin2D(full_array, sub_arrays)
Out[216]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False,  True]])
```

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail how the broadcasting solution works?