# How to remove all round table permutations from all permutations of a 1d Numpy array?

Tags: python

I have this vector: [a,a,b,c,c] It is a pattern that is repeating itself in infinity, and I want to find all circular unique permutations of it.

[a,a,b,c,c] = [a,b,c,c,a]  **not ok** (shifted 1 step to the right)

[a,a,b,c,c] = [b,c,c,a,a] **not ok** (shifted 2 steps to the right)

[a,c,b,a,c] **ok**
[b,c,a,a,c] **ok**

An analogy would be: A round table with 5 seats. Position two males, to females and one child (genderless) in all possible unique ways.

is there a smart function for this numpy, scipy etc
Would really much appreciate help.

Br Erik

Comment: How is the first one not ok and the second yes? What is your definition of circular?

Comment: It is a rotating device so the pattern is repeating in infinity. ...1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,-1,-1... so  it doesn't matter where we start looking.

Comment: Your second "ok" example `[1,-1,0,1,-1]` does not appear in that pattern, so why is it ok?

Comment: Thats the point it, is not in that pattern... I want to have all unique patterns.
If we have a round table with 5 seats I want to position the persons (values)  i all the unique ways. Where the first person sits does not matter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then something like this can help you

```
from itertools import permutations


vector = [1,-1,0,1,-1]
unique_permutations = set(permutations(vector))
already_reviewed = []
for p in list(unique_permutations):
    if p not in already_reviewed:
        circular_permutations = [p[i:] + p[:i] for i in range(len(p))]
        already_reviewed.extend(circular_permutations)
        unique_permutations.difference_update(circular_permutations[1:])

print(unique_permutations)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a vectorized solution inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352527/check-for-identical-rows-in-different-numpy-arrays) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631460/using-numpy-isin-element-wise-between-2d-and-1d-arrays):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

a = [1,1,0,-1,-1]

perms = np.array(list(set(permutations(a))))

# create all possible cyclic permutations, 
all_cyclic = np.array([np.roll(a, i) for i in range(perms.shape[1])])

def find_rows(remove_me, from_here):
    b = remove_me
    a = from_here

    # expand axis for broadcasting
    idx = a[:, np.newaxis, :] == b[np.newaxis ,: ,:]
    print(idx.shape)

    # in broadcasted array find identical arrays .all(-1)
    # that are IN `from_here`
    return idx.all(-1).any(-1)

x = find_rows(all_cyclic, perms)

# now we need to invert the result  
not_x = np.logical_not(x)

# now we can use not_x to pick the non-cyclic things
# from perms
perms_without = perms[not_x]

# TEST
for _ in all_cyclic:

    # to bool: numpy.array(old_matrix, dtype=bool)
    # or old_matrix != 0

    diff = (_ - perms) != 0
    print('in perms', np.any(np.all(np.logical_not(diff), axis=-1)))

    diff = _ - perms_without
    print('in perms without', np.any(np.all(np.logical_not(diff), axis=-1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not the cyclic permutations i want. I want all permutation with the cyclic ones excluded...

Comment: Hm, your question states *I want to find all circular unique permutations*.  Or you may have to write *I want to find all permutations but without circular permutations* Maybe you are using circular in a misleading way as this would be something like all shifted 1, all shifted 2, etc. around the table.

Comment: I added a vectorized solution.