# how to get the index of the subarray in pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

a and b are torch tensor No repeating elements
a shape is [n,2] like:

```
[[1,2]
[2,3]
[4,6]
...]
```

b is[m,2] like:

```
[[1,2]
[4,6]
....
]
```

how to get the index of b in a, example:

```
a = [[1,2]
[2,4]
[6,7]
]
b = [[1,2]
[6,7]]
```

the index should be (0,3), we can use gpu，

Comment: the index should be (0, 2), isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here @jpp 's, `numpy` solution is almost your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51352806/6075699) after this

You just need to get indices using [`nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.nonzero) and flatten tensor using [`flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.flatten) to get expected shape.

```py
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [6, 7]])
```

```py
(a[:, None] == b).all(-1).any(-1).nonzero().flatten()
tensor([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of the following trick that can work for you.

Since we have two tensors with different numbers of rows (n and m), first we transform them into the same shape (`m x n x 2`) and then subtract. If two rows match, then after subtraction, the entire row will be zero. Then, we need to identify the indices of those rows.

```
n = a.shape[0] # 3
m = b.shape[0] # 2
_a = a.unsqueeze(0).repeat(m, 1, 1) # m x n x 2
_b = b.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, n, 1) # m x n x 2

match = (_a - _b).sum(-1) # m x n
indices = (match == 0).nonzero()
if indices.nelement() > 0: # empty tensor check
    row_indices = indices[:, 1]
else:
    row_indices = []

print(row_indices)
```

---

**Sample Input/Output**

> Example 1

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [6, 7]])
```

```
tensor([0, 2])
```

> Example 2

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 3], [6, 7]])
```

```
tensor([2])
```

> Example 3

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [6, 5], [8, 9]])
```

```
tensor([0])
```

> Example 4

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [2, 4], [6, 7]])
b = torch.tensor([[1, 3], [6, 5], [8, 9]])
```

```
[]
```