# Rowwise numpy.isin for 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have two arrays:

```py
A = np.array([[3, 1], [4, 1], [1, 4]])
B = np.array([[0, 1, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5]])
```

Is it possible to use `numpy.isin` rowwise for 2D arrays? I want to check if `A[i,j]` is in `B[i]` and return this result into `C[i,j]`. At the end I would get the following `C`:

```py
np.array([[False, True], [True, False], [False, False]])
```

It would be great, if this is also doable with the `==` operator, then I could use it also with PyTorch.

**Edit:**
I also considered [check for identical rows in different numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51352527/11227118). The question is somehow similar, but I am not able to apply its solutions to this slightly different problem.

Comment: Are sublists of B always sorted?

Comment: Please use Divakar's solution, not the accepted answer. The accepted answer makes some unnecessary temp arrays.

Comment: Both of the solutions here have the same problems

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, no this was just by accident

Comment: @MadPhysicist none of the answers have been accepted so far

Comment: @Christian. To the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51352806/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist what are the problems with the solutions here?

Comment: @Christian. They are the same as the accepted one there. They are totally functional, but create massive and unnecessary temporary arrays, which can be eliminated by calling in1d with properly viewed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that my code solves your problem perfectly. please run it on more test cases to confirm. but i would do smth like i've done in the following code taking advantage of numpys vector outer operations ability (similar to vector outer product). If it works as intended it should work with pytorch as well.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[3, 1], [4, 1], [1, 4]])
B = np.array([[0, 1, 5], [2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5]])

AA = A.reshape(3, 2, 1)
BB = B.reshape(3, 1, 3)
(AA == BB).sum(-1).astype(bool)
```

output:

```
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like this. In contrast to the answer of Whole Brain, this code works also if `A` and `B` have the same dimension. You can reduce it to one line: `(A[:,:,None] == B[:,None,:).any(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated answer

Here is a way to do this :

```
(A == B[..., None]).any(axis=1).astype(bool)
# > array([[False,  True],
#          [ True, False],
#          [False, False]])
```

#### Previous answer

You could also do it inside a list comprehension:

```
[np.isin(a, b) for a,b in zip(A, B)]
# > [array([False,  True]), array([ True, False]), array([False, False])]
np.array([np.isin(a, b) for a,b in zip(A, B)])
# > array([[False,  True],
#          [ True, False],
#          [False, False]])
```

But, as @alex said it defeats the purpose of numpy.

Comment: loops defeat the whole purpose of Numpy...

Comment: Thanks @WholeBrain, I think I tried that, but unfortunately that did not work if `B` has the same dimension as `A`  (in this case 2 columns).