# How to sort an already sorted array in non-decreasing order O(N) time complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The problem:

**Given a sorted array in non-decreasing order, return an array of squares of each number, also in non-decreasing order. For example:
[-4,-2,-1,0,3,5] -> [0,1,4,9,16,25]**

I'm trying two-pointer approach. Comparing the absolute value of two extreme values and then adding that to a new list. Here is the code:

```
def make_square(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return Null
    left = 0
    right = len(arr)-1
    result = len(arr) * [None]
    result_ind = len(result)-1

    while left < right:
        if abs(arr[left]) > abs(arr[right]):
            result[result_ind] = (arr[left])**2
            left +=1
        else:
            result[result_ind] = (arr[right])**2
            right -=1
        result_ind -=1
    return result

make_square([-4,-2,-1,0,3,5])
```

However, I'm getting the following result:

[None, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Think about when `left == right`, and what you do in that case.

Comment: `in non-decreasing order` you mean ascending order? ascending order is opposite to descending. Make your comparision right and you should be good

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The slight difference between the two is whether `a[i+1] > a[i]` for all `i`, or `a[i+1] >= a[i]`.

Comment: re: "increasing" vs "non-decreasing" https://stackoverflow.com/q/1963474/56778

Answer (score 2):

```
def make_square(arr):
if arr == []:
    return Null
left = 0
right = len(arr)-1
result = len(arr) * [None]
print(result)
result_ind = len(result)-1

while left <= right:           #You missed the starting case where left is equal to right
    if abs(arr[left]) > abs(arr[right]):
        result[result_ind] = (arr[left])**2
        left +=1
    else:
        result[result_ind] = (arr[right])**2
        right -=1
    result_ind -=1
return result

make_square([-4,-2,-1,0,3,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be made very short using some less-used features in Python: an explicit `list_iterator` for iterating over the input, a deque, and `heapq.merge`.

```
from heapq import merge
from collections import deque


def make_square(arr):
    itr = iter(arr)
    neg = deque()
    for x in itr:
        if x >= 0:
            break
        neg.appendleft(x**2)

    return list(merge(neg, [x**2], (x**2 for x in itr)))
```

We only use the `for` loop, with its repeated sign checks, until we see the first
non-negative value. Until we do, we *prepend* the square of each input value
to a deque to keep the squares in non-decreasing order. (Prepending to a list
is far less efficient.)

`merge` takes three iterables:

- The precomputed squares of the negative values, in non-decreasing order
- The singleton list containing the square of the first non-negative input value
- A generator producing the squares of the rest of the input values

and returns an iterable of the squares in non-decreasing order.

(Ideally, we could just push `x` back on to `itr` before breaking out of the loop, but we can't, and the workarounds aren't any cleaner than simply passing a third argument to `merge`.)

Comment: Hi Chepner. Thanks for the new insights. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
def make_square(arr):
    return sorted([a**2 for a in arr])

print(make_square([-4,-2,-1,0,3,5]))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: This doesn't take advantage of the knowledge that `arr` is already sorted. (CPython's sorting algorithm is optimized to take advantage of runs of sorted elements in its input, but as far as I know that's an implementation detail, not a language guarantee.)

Comment: The input is known to be in non-decreasing order, and the output is supposed to be in non-decreasing order. At worst, a naive squaring of the input values will produce a sequence that can be split into a non-increasing prefix to be reversed and a non-deceasing suffix; the two can then be merged.

Comment: Absent the optimization I mentioned, using `sort` would mean an O(n lg n) operation for something that can be done in O(n) time. (But with the optimization, sorting is almost certainly fine.)

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the O(n) time requirement.

Comment: @JimMischel If the sorting algorithm isn't specified, it's O(n lg n), but if you assume [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), it's O(n) due to the bitonic nature of the input.